# Association among three models in Netzke

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, netzke

I have 3 models: Machine,Mouse,KeyBoard these are in association.

```
class Machine
  has_many: mouses
  has_many: keyboards
end

class Mouse
  belongs_to: machine
end

class KeyBoard
  belongs_to: machine
end
```

these associations are working fine.

But, I want to display the three grids in netzke through `OneToManyExplorer`

```
class MachineExplorer < Netzke::Communitypack::OneToManyExplorer
title "Machines"
 title "Machines"
 container_config class_name: "MachineGrid",
                   region: :north,
                   height: 200,
                   width: 150
 collection_config class_name: "MachineKeyBoardGrid", 
                   region: :east,
                   height: 200,
                   width: 100,
                   split: true                

 collection_config class_name: "MachineMouseGrid",
                   region: :center,
                   height: 200,
                   width: 150

end
```

But it's showing two grid's only. `MachineGrid` and `MachineMouseGrid`. I want `MachineKeyBoardGrid` also.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement it yourself using the following tutorial as a reference: 
https://github.com/netzke/netzke/wiki/Building-a-composite-component

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the important parts of the link into your answer as links can break.